# Magento 2.1 overriding base product images

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images

What I am wanting to do is override the Magento default image when a product does not have an image (the faint 'M' logo).

When I set the placeholder, it does not replace the image in product details.

So what I am doing now is seeking to override the defaults. They are located
`module_catalog/view/base/web/images/product/placeholder/image.jpg`

How do I correctly override them? I have tried including my own images in my theme structure with the same name, so far has not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override image inside below path,

This is the correct path,

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/Magento_Catalog/web/images/product/placeholder/image.jpg
```

Remove var and clear cache.

Comment: This worked for thumbnails and small images, thank you. However, the normal image.jpg does not get overridden and does not appear in static files. So the product page still shows magento defualt image :(

Comment: You can override your default product image from backend, Content ->  Design -> Configuration -> CLick your theme -> Product image watermark set image.

Comment: My apologies, this whole time I'm thinking I'm not doing it correctly or it is not working, however, it seems to be a caching issue with the browser. I tested in a different browser and is working. Thank you. You are correct with the above path to override images.